# How to pass variable value as a pandas dataframe column name

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get only certain rows from pandas DataFrame. I have a dataframe about hotels, the strucuture is like this

```
         pool      gym         AC     Breakfast
hotel1    1          0         1          0    
hotel2    0          0         0          1
hotel3    0          1         1          0  
....
```

Now the user can choose which requirements they have e.g. a hotel with pool and AC. I want to remove the rows that don't match any of the criteria the user has given. So for the example the hotel2 would removed from the dataframe.

I have tried to loop through the user's given criteria and create a condition that would only leave rows that match at least one given attribute.

This works if I have hard coded the options, like this.

```
hotels = hotels([hotels.pool == 1) | (hotels.AC == 1)]
```

However since the user given criteria changes all the time I have build a loop that would generate the corrent criteria. Like this:

```
for key, value in usercriteria.items():
    criteria += '(hotels[\'' + key + '\'] == 1) | '

# remove last OR operator
criteria = criteria[:-2]
```

However I don't know how I can pass that variable value to replace the needed criteria to the dataframe to only give the correct rows. I have tried following formats:

```
hotels = hotels[criteria]
```

With the first I get key error: KeyError: "(hotels['pool'] == 1) | (hotels['AC'] == 1) "

However If I copy / paste the key from the error message and repace the criteria with that it seems to work.

How should I pass that variable so it would be placed correctly? Is it the single quotes that are problematic?

Comment: You can not use a string to select from a dataframe with brackets [ ]. But you can use the "query" method, it has a similar syntax, and will do what you need [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Comment: This did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate an expression as a string use [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.eval.html):

```
import pandas as pd

usercriteria = {"pool": 1, "AC":1}

criteria = "hotels["
for key, value in usercriteria.items():
    criteria += "(hotels['{}']=={})|".format(key, value)
criteria = criteria[:-1] + "]"

>>> print(pd.eval(criteria))
        pool  gym  AC  Breakfast
hotel                           
hotel1     1    0   1          0
hotel3     0    1   1          0
```

Also, as @GeorgPoe suggested, you can use the `DataFrame` method [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
usercriteria = {"pool": 1, "AC":1}

criteria = ""
for key, value in usercriteria.items():
    criteria += "({}=={})|".format(key, value)
criteria = criteria[:-1]

>>> print(hotels.query(criteria))
        pool  gym  AC  Breakfast
hotel                           
hotel1     1    0   1          0
hotel3     0    1   1          0
```